# How to wrap a decorator around another classes method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have created a decorator which I am using to manage logging. I want logging to occur before and after the decorated function runs. The function works fine when interacting with very basic functions, however, when interacting with methods that are a part of other classes, things break. I suspect the issue is a result of there being 2 `self` arguments. Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Simplified Decorator Class

```
class Logger:

    def __init__(self, logging_type:str = 'debug'):
        self.logging_type = logging_type

    def __call__(self, decorated_function:callable):
        self.func = decorated_function
        return getattr(self, self.logging_type)

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("starting function")
        output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Completing Function")
        return output
```

We see that the decorator works on basic functions:

```
@Logger(logging_type="debug")
def simple_function(x):
    return x**2

In [2]: simple_function(3)
starting function
Completing Function
Out[2]: 9
```

However, fails when work with other classes:

```
class BigClass:

    def __init__(self, stuff = 10):
        self.stuff = stuff

    @Logger(logging_type="debug")
    def cool_function(self, input1: int):
        return self.stuff + input1


In [16]: test = BigClass()
    ...: test.cool_function(3)
starting function
```

It then hits a type error on the output line:

```
TypeError: cool_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input1'
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all means read juanpa.arrivillaga's informative answer.  But here is a simpler approach.  In writing a class decorator of this type, `__call__` should return an ordinary function instead of a member function, like this:

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, logging_type:str = 'debug'):
        self.logging_function = getattr(self, logging_type)

    def __call__(self, decorated_function: callable):
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.logging_function(decorated_function, *args, **kwargs)
        return f

    def debug(self, decorated_function, *args, **kwargs):
        print("starting function")
        output = decorated_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Completing Function")
        return output

@Logger(logging_type="debug")
def simple_function(x):
    return x**2

class BigClass:
    def __init__(self, stuff = 10):
        self.stuff = stuff

    @Logger(logging_type="debug")
    def cool_function(self, input1: int):
        return self.stuff + input1

print(simple_function(12))

test = BigClass()
print(test.cool_function(3))
```

OUTPUT:

```
starting function
Completing Function
144
starting function
Completing Function
13
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are decorating your function with a bound-method type, look at `type(BigClass.cool_function)`, you'll see something like: `<bound method Logger.debug of <__main__.Logger object at 0x11081f7c0>`. Since bound-method objects aren't functions, they don't implement the descriptor protocol to bind the instance as the first argument, hence, the instance is never passed implicitly as the first argument.

The best solution is to avoid class-based decorators to begin with. Here's how you could implement what you are doing using function-based decorators, using the closures to maintain internal state:

```
from functools import wraps

def logger(*, logging_type): # I prefer keyword-only arugments for decorators, but that is your call...
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def debug(*args, **kwargs):
            print("starting function")
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("ending function")
            return result
        @wraps(func)
        def another_option(*args, **kwargs):
            print("another option")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        options = {"debug": debug, "another_option": another_option}
        return options[logging_type]
    return decorator

class BigClass:
    def __init__(self, stuff = 10):
        self.stuff = stuff
    @logger(logging_type="debug")
    def cool_function(self, input1: int):
        return self.stuff + input1
    @logger(logging_type="another_option")
    def another_function(self):
        return self.stuff*100
```